# Limit of integral gives incorrect output

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I'm trying to evaluate
$\lim_{e\to 0} \, \frac{i}{e}\int_{\pi }^0 \frac{1-\exp (i e \exp (i \theta ))}{\exp (i \theta )} \, d\theta$ with Mathematica 9.0.1.0 on OS X.

However, I get "Undefined" for this input:

```
Limit[I/e Integrate[(1 - Exp[I e Exp[I θ]])/Exp[I θ], {θ, π, 0}], e -> 0]
```

We can see numerically that the correct answer is $-\pi$ by using this code:

```
With[{e = 0.000001}, I/e NIntegrate[(1 - Exp[I e Exp[I θ]])/Exp[I θ], {θ, π, 0}] ] // Chop
```

What goes wrong in this process? Is it possible to get the correct result?

Comment: Giving an assumption on that epsilon will help. `Limit[
 I/eps*Integrate[(1 - Exp[I eps Exp[I \[Theta]]])/
    Exp[I \[Theta]], {\[Theta], \[Pi], 0}, 
   Assumptions -> 0 < eps < 1/1000], eps -> 0]

Out[329]= -\[Pi]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some issue with the definite integral. But you can easily work around it by using indefinite integration then evaluate for the limit of integration (replaced your $\theta$ with $x$ to paste here)

```
 r = Integrate[(1 - Exp[I e Exp[I x]])/Exp[I x], x];
-((r /. x -> Pi) - (r /. x -> 0));
Limit[I/e*%, e -> 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mathematica 9.01 on windows

One can see something is strange, by doing:

```
r = Integrate[(1 - Exp[I e Exp[I x]])/Exp[I x], {x, \[Pi], 0}]
Assuming[Re[e] <= 0 && Im[e] == 0, Limit[I/e*r, e -> 0]]
```

Where did this 1/4096 value come from?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
Assuming[s \[Element] Reals && s > 0, 
 Limit[I/s Integrate[(1 - Exp[I s Exp[I t]])/Exp[I t], {t, Pi, 0}], 
  s -> 0]]
```

yields $-\pi$ (Mathematica 9.0). The integral yields a conditional expression  which renders limit undefined without declaring assumptions. There is a difficulty (probably related to periodicity) if you try to bypass by using generate conditions to false. The limit returned is $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`AsymptoticIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticIntegrate):

```
I/e AsymptoticIntegrate[(1 - Exp[I e Exp[I θ]])/Exp[I θ, {θ, π, 0}, {e, 0, 1}]
```

> -π